# ViewModel/LiveData/Observer Design

Tags: java, android

My app fetches Top Rated or Most Popular movies from themoviedb.org.

[image]

I'm trying to implement ViewModel with LiveData to toggle these two buttons.  In MainViewModel.java, I have this:

```
    //private static long String TAG = MainViewModel.class.getSimpleName();
    public LiveData<List<MovieRoom>> movies;
    private AppDatabase database;


    /*
        Use constructor to initialize all data that UI needs to populate
     */
    public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        // how do I know this was initialized correctly?
        database = AppDatabase.getInstance(this.getApplication());
        //database = AppDatabase.getInstance(application);
        //movies is null after calling ViewModelProvider constructor

        // what are the values in movies?
        // _movieDao = null, mDatabase = null
        movies = database.movieDao().getAllMovies();
    }


    // Loads most popular movies
    public void loadData() {
        //MainViewModel.FetchMovieTask movies = new MainViewModel.FetchMovieTask();
        //movies.execute("popular");
        // Assign to movies
    }

    public void getAllMovies() {
        movies = database.movieDao().getAllMovies();
    }

    public void getPopularMovies() {
        movies = database.movieDao().getPopularMovies();
    }

    public void getTopRatedMovies() {
        movies = database.movieDao().getTopRatedMovies();
    }

    public void getFavoriteMovies() {
        movies = database.movieDao().loadFavoriteMovies(true);
    }

}
```

In my MainActivity.java, the buttons have an onclick listener and I have set the observer as the following:

```
        b_pop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //updateMovies("popular");
                mViewModel.getPopularMovies();
            }
        });
```

```
mViewModel.movies.observe(this, new Observer<List<MovieRoom>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MovieRoom> movieEntries) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "Receiving database update from LiveData");
                // mMovieAdapter.mMovies = 0
                mMovieAdapter.clear();
                // movieEntries = 0
                // mMovieAdapter mMovies = 0
                mMovieAdapter.setList(movieEntries);
                mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Problem is, when you reassign the ViewModel's "movies" variable with top rated or most popular list of movies, it doesn't trigger onChanged().  The Top Rated list of movies is the same list of movies as the most popular, but just in different order.  So onChanged() is never triggered and I will not be able to set it to the adapter.

I'm learning ViewModel, LiveData and observer from 0 so not sure how to redesign this so that it can work?

Comment: Observer may not be triggered after `onPause`, it will be triggered when after `onResume` called.

Comment: Change `LiveData` to `MutableLiveData`. For context, mutable means changeable. ;-)

Comment: So if "movies" is LiveData like it is now, and I assign it getTopRatedMovies(), then the value won't change?  It has to be MutableLiveData before the value will change?

Comment: And in terms of LiveData, does it trigger onChanged() if the order of the entries in "movies" variable is changed?  Or does it only trigger onChanged() if a field in any of the entries in the database has changed?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value of newly fetched data to the ViewModel using `value` on your LiveData:

```
public void getAllMovies() {
        movies.setValue(database.movieDao().getAllMovies().getValue())
}
```

Also you need MutableLiveData

```
public MutableLiveData<List<MovieRoom>> movies;
```

Comment: So I need MutableLiveData in order to reassign the "movies" new values?  And LiveData is only in the case that I'm reading values from LiveData?

Comment: you replace the content of LiveData not the object refrence itself. so yes, you need to update the content of it.

Comment: There is the issue of the initial loading of the data via AsyncTask.  Is there a specific place this should be done in order that the execution happens such that the movies will be put into the Room Database before this ViewModel is instantiated?